# Firefox console getElementBy doesn't work

Tags: google-chrome, firefox

Can someone tell me why when i run

```
document.getElementsByTagName('img')[0]
```

in chrome's console shows what I want and doing the same on firefox does not?

Comment: As a matter of fact, [it does](https://imgur.com/a/SvxTQDc)

Comment: I know it' strange but firefox shows undefined

Comment: That's most definitely because no image exists on the page.

Comment: But why chrome does the same way on your image (obviously i tried the code on the same web page both in chrome and firefox)

Comment: What is the webpage in question?

Comment: I solved it. It was me that haven't thought about how iframes are handled. Anyway thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research I found out I was doing it totally wrong as I would have to load the iframe first and then access it. I wrongly thought that this would be done automatically by the browser.